# Failover sharding mongodb. Autoreconnect doesnt work

Tags: mongodb, replication, sharding

I have configured Sharding for MongoDB. My setup looks like this:

- 3 ConfigServers
- 2 Shard Servers (Shard1 and Shard2) each of them with 3 ReplicaSet nodes
- 1 mongos instance

My current collection has as primary sharding Shard 1. All my data stored right now on Shard 1. Am I right that the data will be stored on Shard 2 as soon as my Shard 1 will get full ?

I'm testing now a failover scenario when my Shard 1 Server is down then the data should go to Shard 2 but it doesnt happen ? It should automatically auto reconnect to Shard 1 right ?

Comment: Sounds like you are sharding wrongly. Both shards should always have around the same amount of data, unless you choose a wrong sharding key. A wrong sharding key, for example a continuously increasing timestamp, would first fill Shard 1 and as far as I know never Shard 2 unless a specific value of the sharding key is reached, which might never occur. Correct sharding would be made on a key which is generated randomly, something like a user ID. That way with 1000 users around 500 would end up on Shard 1 and the rest on Shard 2.

Comment: Sharding is not for failover. That's what the replicas are there for. Sharding is for scaling.

Comment: ok, I chose as a sharding key some ID which is continuously increasing and it looks like only one Shard getting all the data. So if I choose other sharding key like someID + randomString shoould it behave differently, right ?

Comment: If `someID` increases continuously "00001", "00002" and this+randromString would yield "00001-scnkg",  "00002-qeiov", then you'd still have the problem. If you use a hash of the `someID`, you'd get a pretty even balancing of the shards. Read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#choosing-a-shard-key and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/#sharding-strategy

Comment: Reading the docs it appears that MongoDB is automatically hashing the key. Looks like what you're encountering should not be occurring. How strange. Unless you are using Ranged Sharding?

Comment: no I'm using "hashed sharding". I also decreased the size of chunk and trying to fill decreased chunk size and see what will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My current collection has as primary sharding Shard 1. All my data
> stored right now on Shard 1. Am I right that the data will be stored
> on Shard 2 as soon as my Shard 1 will get full ?

Sharding is about distributing data in a collection among shards. Sharding is enabled at database level, but actual data distribution on shards is at collection level. So, a sharded database can have sharded and unsharded collections. All the unsharded collections reside on primary shard. The sharded collection data is distributed on multiple shards (based on shard key). All queries to a sharded database (irrespective of sharded or unsharded collections) go thru the mongos router.

For a sharded collection, it is possible that the initial data is all stored on one shard. Later on as the data grows it is distributed to the next shard. See [data partitioning with chunks](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-data-partitioning/index.html).

> I'm testing now a failover scenario when my Shard 1 Server is down
> then the data should go to Shard 2 but it doesnt happen ? It should
> automatically auto reconnect to Shard 1 right ?

Faliover is a process associated with replication, not sharding. A replica-set has multiple nodes (as specified in your shard configuration, each shard is a replica-set). When a primary node in the replica-set fails (or goes down) the remaining two secondaries hold an election and elect a new primary. The client applications will automatically connect to the new primary. When the previous primary node comes up again, it will become a seconday.

See [replication failover](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/index.html#automatic-failover).

Comment: I reduced the chunk size of Shard 1 and now data  is distributed on multiple shards. But as soon as one of my Shard goes down than Shard 2 stop getting the data. I wrote some small app which is inserting data in sharded mongoDB and it stops if one of the shard unavailable. I dont understand why?

Comment: You are using replica-sets as shard nodes. What do you mean by "one of my Shard goes down"? A node (server) on a shard _or_ all the nodes (complete replica-set) on a shard?

Comment: If a shard (complete replica-set) is not available the application can still use the available shards for read-update operations. Only, the data on the shard which is not available cannot be accessed (till it comes up).

Comment: My replica set for shard has 3 members and if 2 of them down then complete replica set is not available. and that I was meaning by "shard goes down".

Comment: it looks like that for write operations its not available if one of the shard not reachable, right ?

Comment: The write operations on the other running shards will  be there, normally.

Comment: The relationship between shard-key and chunks plays part in this. A shard-key is always on one chunk. So, if you are trying to write data with shard-key whose chunk is on the shard which is down, the write will not happen. But, you can still write to other shards which have data (chunks with other shard keys) .

Comment: its getting a bit clear but I have still some questions. You said "chunks with other shard keys" so can one collection has different shard keys ? I created one collection with "hashed" shard-key and trying to write data on multiple shards. So probably all chunks on two shards have same shard-key and that's why it happened. How to avoid this situation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202349/discussion-between-prasad-and-ldropl).